# String comparison issue in Jade Template in NodeJs Express framework application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm comparing two variables in Jade Template in my NodeJs (Express Framework) application.
I can see that values are same but not sure why it's not working.
Below is the piece of code.

```
select#corpid.form-control.grid-select(name='corpid', style='display: none', value='#{ScheduleList.CorpId}', onchange="setEmployer(this)")
    each item in Employers
        if(new String(item.EmployerId) == new String(ScheduleList.ProdEmployerId))
            option(value = '#{item.EmployerId}', selected='selected') #{item.AccountName}
        else
            option(value = '#{item.EmployerId}', eid="#{new String(item.EmployerId)}", pid="#{new String(ScheduleList.ProdEmployerId)}") #{item.AccountName}
```

[image]

You can see above, i showed both ids which is coming same for id=101 but still it is not adding **selected** attribute as per **if** block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

var s_prim = 'foo';
var s_obj = new String(s_prim);

console.log(typeof s_prim); // Logs "string"
console.log(typeof s_obj);  // Logs "object"

String primitives and String objects also give different results when ==
A simple run like new 
String('a') == new String('a') 
would prove the point, use s_obj .valueOf() to convert into primitive and it would work

Answer (score -1):

Your are testing String equality with `new String(...) == new String(...)` which is not the way to go. 
You are actually comparing the String **objects** which are definitely not the same. In order to properly compare two strings you have to use `new String(item.EmployerId).valueOf() === new String(ScheduleList.ProdEmployerId).valueOf()` or `String(item.EmployerId) === String(ScheduleList.ProdEmployerId)` as `String()` converts an object to a String primitive.

Comment: equals is in java and I'm asking in nodeJs.

Comment: sorry read too fast, will update the answer (which is still similar)